# Why is output voltage of current-to-voltage amplifier the same when input resistance is larger

Tags: amplifier

Whenever we increase the resistance (imagine putting a bigger resistor in front of an amplifier) going into a current-to-voltage amplifier, why does the output voltage of that amplifier stay the same.

What i would expect whenever the resistance increases with for example 2 times is that the voltage would be 2 times lower, because U = IR and therefore I = U/R. Thus if we increase resistance by two times, the current halves. Therefore the current-to-voltage amplifier has halve of the amps as input and therefore it puts out half of the voltage.

But according to some answer to a test question the voltage does nto noticeably change whenever we change the resistance.

Comment: Please post a schematic, (there is a tool that you can use if you edit your qeuestion) or post an image

Comment: A schematic is not really needed. It is a general question about putting a larger resistor in front of a current to voltage amplifier and about why the voltage then stays the same

Comment: If you have a current source driving your current-to-voltage (transimpedance) amplifier, then within the compliance of the current source any series resistance won't affect the current.  Therefore no voltage change.

Comment: @darkness A schematic actually is useful here because it would probably show you forgot about the nature of the signal source feeding the input of the amplifier. You might have found the answer yourself as you were drawing your schematic. Would you use a voltage amplifier for a current source signal (at least, without a parallel resistor to convert it to a voltage first)? No. So why would you use a current amplifier for a voltage source signal? In other words, why are you wanting to use a current amplifier with a voltage signal source? It's probably a current signal source.

Comment: A schematic is **necessary**. We need to know what kind of source is driving the input. We need to know how the size of this added resistance compares to the input resistance of the amplifier.

Answer (score 3):

I = V/R only applies when the source is a voltage source. A current source is not affected by input resistance, at least not until you exceed its compliance range.